# How to detect collision between CCNode and CCSprite?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am developing a game with a ball and some bars. I created the ball as a ccsprite in the gamelayer and the bars as nodes. the problem is cocos2d can't seem to detect collision between the ball and the bars. Here is the code i use. This is the gameplayer.m.

```
     -(id)init{


    if((self= [super init])){

        CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector]winSize];

        self.isTouchEnabled = YES;

        ball = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"redball final.png"];
        ball.position = ccp(150,300);
        [self addChild:ball z:1];

        barOne = [Bar node];
        [self addchild:barOne];



        moveAction = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:5 position:ccp(barOne.position.x,-winSize.height)];



        [barOne runAction:moveAction];




        [self addChild:barOne];


        [self schedule:@selector(update:)];




    }
    return self;
}

-(void) update:(ccTime)dt
{
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(ball.boundingBox,barOne.boundingBox))

   {
        [self removeChild:ball];
   }

}
```

Comment: If this is your actual code, you'll be adding barOne as child twice to the same parent, this will assert / crash. Are you sure the class containing this code is created correctly? Set a breakpoint and step through.

Comment: sorry i added it here by mistake, the code only contains 1 [self addchild:barOne];

Comment: Can you check the sizes of the bounding boxes?